# "Flashlight" hat not awarded with theme set to "System setting" when dark mode engages

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020

Not sure if this is intentional or not; however, given the description is "Try Dark Mode" and not "Set the theme to Dark Mode", I figured I'd bring it up.

At least under Safari 14.0, with the theme set to "System setting" on SO and the system setting set to dark, the hat is not awarded.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to close the tab, open it again.

Comment: @ppwater Have done a few times, no success :/

Comment: Hmm, I think it's only triggered by dark mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the way that it is set up. The hat will only trigger if you have your setting set to `Dark` (and not `System setting`).

> want to get Flashlight?
> set user preferences
> to: -quote- Dark -unquote-

Answer (score -3):

You probably need to wait for a bit.

Come back to the site in 5 minutes and check again.

It took me like 3-4 minutes to get the Social distancing ones for the other sites.

Comment: Most of my badges have been awarded in under 5 minutes; it's been about an hour so far with this badge and no luck.